# GetPreviousValue JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

With the following HTML and code, I need to get the value `Resolve` when clicking the link. What's wrong with this code?

```js
$(function() {
  $('.link').click(function() {
    var link = $(this).prev('Ans').innerText;
    alert(link);
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="Ans">
  <h4 class="header">Author</h4>
  Resolve
  <input type="hidden" value="1">
  <a class="link">Link</a>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('.link').click(function() {
  var text = $(".Ans").contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
  }).text();
  alert(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Ans">
  <h4 class="header">Author</h4>
  Resolve
  <input type="hidden" value="1">
  <a class="link">Link</a>
</div>
```

Use the `contents()` then get node 3 which is text

```js
$('.link').click(function() {
  var text = $(this).closest(".Ans").contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
  }).text();
  alert(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Ans">
  <h4 class="header">Author</h4>
  Resolve
  <input type="hidden" value="1">
  <a class="link">Link</a>
</div>

<div class="Ans">
  <h4 class="header">Author</h4>
  Resolve1
  <input type="hidden" value="1">
  <a class="link">Link</a>
</div>


<div class="Ans">
  <h4 class="header">Author</h4>
  Resolve2
  <input type="hidden" value="1">
  <a class="link">Link</a>
</div>
```

When there are multiple `Ans classes` use `.closest()` with `this` context

Comment: but if I have many Ans classes? its show all content all Anses

Comment: then use `$(this).closest('.Ans')`